# How do I eliminate duplicate rows where only timestamp is different?

Tags: sql, duplicates, timestamp, rows

I have joined two tables together, and I'm looking to eliminate the duplicate rows. The rows are duplicating because each row has a different timestamp. Ideally, I just want the row with the most up-to-date timestamp, and then I want it to move on to the next vehicle.

[image]

[image]

Note how it did not repeat Ford Fusion and moved on to the Nissan entry. Also they have the most recent timestamps?

I tried using 'RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Make ORDER BY Timestamp) AS rank1' and then filtered rank1 =1 but didn't get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

The typical solution would be to use `row_number`:

```
with x as (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by make, model order by Timestamp desc) rn
  from t
)
select Make, Model, Timestamp, Id
from x
where rn=1
```